# How can I retrieve and copy all photos/videos from Photos app to my app programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ipad

How can I retrieve and copy all photos/videos from Photos app to my application programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of [ALAssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/assetslibrary/alassetslibrary) for iOS 4.0–9.0, or the [Photos framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/) for iOS 8.0 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible - Apple doesn't allow access to the photo library. (although i'm sure there is a way through jailbreak/private methods, but it won't be sanctioned by Apple).

You can, however, save photos with [UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) and pick photos manually from the photo library with [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html).

EDIT: Actually, it looks like you can get photos using the Assets Library. Check out this [tutorial](http://www.fiveminutes.eu/accessing-photo-library-using-assets-library-framework-on-iphone/).

Comment: I want to access all images at once. Is this possible using UIImagePickerController? Even I don't want present UIImagePickerController to user.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'm mistaken, it's possible using ALAssetsLibrary (though I haven't tried). Look at this [tutorial](http://goo.gl/jmCQw), and at the documentation for [ALAsset](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [ALAssetRepresentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).